# HTML elements not updating from event handlers when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything works perfectly fine on large width sizes, but when it comes to smaller screen sizes that I have to use the menu button, HTML doesn't get updated by event handlers (even though it appears to work fine when I check with `console.log()`).
Now, suppose i click on "online" in the mobile view,it wont update the html page but if i scale it to a large width till the button stops appearing,it updates the html. What could be wrong?I appreciate your help.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.alli', () => {
  $(".colu").hasClass("no_display") ? (console.log("Yes"), $(".colu").removeClass("no_display")) : console.log("no");
  ($("#online").hasClass("oncli")) ? ($("#online").removeClass("oncli"), $("#all").addClass("oncli")) :
  ($("#offline").hasClass("oncli")) ? ($("#offline").removeClass("oncli"), $("#all").addClass("oncli")) :
  console.log("Adding class oncli");
});

$(document).on('click', '.onlinei', () => {
  $("#offline").hasClass("oncli") ? ($("#offline").removeClass("oncli"), $("#online").addClass("oncli")) :
    $("#all").hasClass("oncli") ? ($("#all").removeClass("oncli"), $("#online").addClass("oncli")) :
    console.log("Adding class oncli");
  $(".online").hasClass("no_display") ? (console.log("yes"), $(".online").removeClass("no_display"), $(".offline").addClass("no_display")) :
    $(".offline").hasClass("no_display") ? console.log("already in online views") : $(".offline").addClass("no_display");
});
$(document).on('click', '.offlinei', () => {
  $("#all").hasClass("oncli") ? ($("#all").removeClass("oncli"), $("#offline").addClass("oncli")) :
    $("#online").hasClass("oncli") ? ($("#online").removeClass("oncli"), $("#offline").addClass("oncli")) :
    console.log("Adding class oncli");
  $(".offline").hasClass("no_display") ? (console.log("yes"), $(".offline").removeClass("no_display"), $(".online").addClass("no_display")) :
    $(".online").hasClass("no_display") ? console.log("already in offline views") : $(".online").addClass("no_display");
});


$(document).on('paste copy cut keyup keydown', '#search-bar', () => {
      ($("#search-bar").val() === "search") ? $("#search-bar").val(""): console.log("searching..");
      $(".name").each(function() {
        ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#search-bar").val()) > -1) ? $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("no_display"):
          ($(this).parent().parent().addClass("no_display"));
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was a CSS property `display:inline-block` in the @media, that caused the abnormal behaviour.